# Spring boot background process

Tags: java, spring

I have a web application using spring boot. The user can create jobs and save job parameters to a database. One of the parameters is the job execution time. How to do the following:

1. User create in website a job with parameters and save it.
2. Go tosuccess page immediately.
3. Run a background process in execution timeand do work with file...

My plan is to send a request to the database every minute and find out if the job is to run.  I do not know if this is a good solution, for example a problem with multiple jobs at the same time. Too i do not know how to make background in spring...

Comment: Hi Imana. Please show the relevant code you have tried.

Comment: What you're looking for is [Spring Scheduling](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). It is a part of Spring that allows you to run jobs or tasks on a schedule or timer.

Comment: Ok and when i make a async process in spring, can i create a queue for jobs in this process? It is posible to have a queue and while is not empty do work with jobs or when is empty do nothing?